# React: Keyboard event listener not working unless click on body

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like my app to show a component if the user hits `/`. This should happen right from the beginning, as soon as the page is loaded so this is what I wrote:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React; 

function App() {
  const [showComponent, setShowComponent] = useState(false);

  const onKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "/") setShowComponent(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      {showComponent && (
        <h3 style={{ color: "red" }}>You hit slash my friend!</h3>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

However, if you just load the page and hit slash nothing happens. But if you click anywhere in the page it then works. Any idea of how to make that work without the need of focusing the body?

I setup a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-water-ly4dz?file=/src/App.js:0-642) if you wanna have a look.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Unable to reproduce. The browser needs to be active before it can catch those key events.

Answer (score 2):

Of course the window needs to have focus.

In CodeSandbox, the app itself is in an iframe which changes things, but if you go directly to your sandbox's link, e.g. open https://ly4dz.csb.app/ in a background tab, switch to that tab, don't touch the page at all and hit `/`, the text does appear.

Comment: Uh that's embarassing! thanks! 

The thing at this point is that it does not work in the actual app I am working on, that was a small example in isolation, how can I debug what's causing the event listener not to fire? is it definitely the window not being focused? even if I add a window.focus() after adding the event listener it still doesn't work. Thanks again

Comment: In a different scenario it's not "definitely" the window being focused. Also, `window.focus()` couldn't possibly have the browser steal focus from a non-page element; it sets focus within the page.